# Linq to Sql selection of items with count of nested

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following table structure:

[image]

Using Linq To SQL I want to get a list like this:

```
new {
    E = e,      // the E object
    Ds = e.Ds,  // list of D objects referenced by E
    NumAs = ??? // COUNT OF A objects that are eventually associated with this E
}
```

BUT, I want these things sorted by the number of A's associated with each E.

I've been trying to use combination of joins/orderby and nested queries, but I'm not sure how to get it.

If I make a reference from table E to A, then it seems trivial; I.e. this:

[image]

```
from e in ctx.E
orderby e.As.Count()
select new {
   E     = e,
   Ds    = e.Ds,
   numAs = e.As.Count()
}
```

But is making that reference breaking some kind of DB normalization rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this

```
from e in ctx.E
let ds = e.Ds
let cs = ds.SelectMany(d => d.Cs)
let as = cs.SelectMany(c => c.As)
orderby as.Count()
select new {
   E     = e,
   Ds    = e.Ds,
   numAs = as.Count()
}
```

Or this, for brevity

```
from e in ctx.E
let as = e.Ds.SelectMany(d => d.Cs).SelectMany(c => c.As)
orderby as.Count()
select new {
   E     = e,
   Ds    = e.Ds,
   numAs = as.Count()
}
```

Another way to do it might be to start with `A`s and group them like this:

```
from a in ctx.A
group a by a.C.D.E into g
orderby g.Count()
select new {
    E = g.Key,
    Ds = g.Key.Ds,
    numAs = g.Count()
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Using your third example, I can easily filter based on a specific B.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just follow your entities relations all along:

```
ctx.E.Select(e => new {
                 E = e
               , Ds = e.Ds
               , numAs = e.Ds.SelectMany(d => d.Cs).SelectMany(c => c.As).Count()
                 }
             )
     .OrderBy(e => e.numAs);
```

`e.Ds.SelectMany(d=>d.Cs)` give you all the Cs associated to your e via the Ds.
And again, `SelectMany(c => c.As)` give you all the As associated to your e via the Cs and the Ds.

Comment: Your answer was good too, but I chose @p.s.w.g since he provided more ways to get at it.